# How to delete image from access database

Tags: c#, .net

I successfully insert and update image into an access database. But I need to delete only the image when clicking the update button. I use the following code to update data and image.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
byte[] Logo = ms.ToArray();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblBranchInfo SET BankName=@BankName,BankNameEng=@BankNameEng,BranchName=@BranchName,BranchNameEng=@BranchNameEng,ZoanName=@ZoanName,ZoanNameEng=@ZoanNameEng,ReportHeader=@RHeaderEng,Logo=@Logo WHERE ID=" + txtID.Text + "", conn.con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankName", txtBankName.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankNameEng", txtBankNameEng.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BranchName", txtBranch.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BranchNameEng", txtBranchEng.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ZoanName", txtZoan.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ZoanNameEng", txtZoanEng.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("RHeaderEng", txtRHeader.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Logo", Logo);
```

I created a button named delete image and set a property as pictureBox1.Image==null. I want to delete only Logo image when I press the update button. How can I do that? Anyone help?

Comment: You just need to run an SQL UPDATE command that sets [Logo] to null for the selected item (ID).

Comment: where i set [logo] to null

Comment: Why are you messing with the PictureBox image if you want to remove the image???

Comment: `UPDATE tblBranchInfo SET [Logo] = null WHERE [ID] = @ID` . Don't string concatenate the id into the SQL, use a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In your eventhandler for the delete button:

```
var command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblBranchInfo SET Logo=null WHERE ID=@Id", conn.con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtId.Text);
// ... execute command
```

Do not string concatenate your Id, always use parameters.

Comment: my image deleted from my db but when i click my  datagrid its show an error. "Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'."               My datagrid code:        
                txtID.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();                
                Byte[] Logo = (Byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Logo);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

Comment: How should you be able to read the image when you have deleted it? You have to check whether Logo is null, before you add it to the MemoryStream

Comment: Dear slfan, After delete my image when i click datagridview cell row i want to show the picturebox as null. I want when i need to add image i can add and when i have not need image i can remove. how can i do this?